# Dataverse Data Import + Needing to Grab a ForeignKey -- How would you do this?

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

So the setup looks like this: We have a SQL Server that our WebApp runs off of. We're looking to get into Dynamics, with our first step being the CRM Module and Omnichannel voice.

To do this, I've had my developers boil down our sales into a "real" customer table (believe it or not, we didn't have one before) that will mirror the "contact" table in DV. I've also had them boil down a "sales" table that will mirror "Orders".

The problem that I'm having is that I need to get the backfilled data (about 4k 'customers') from the SQL 'customers' table into the DV 'contact' table, and then I need to take the Dataverse GUID of the 'contact' and push it BACK over to the SQL side so that the two systems can talk.

Small wrinkle is that I've made a custom column in 'contact' called 'WebAppCustomerID' which is the ID key from the SQL table. This is so the systems can talk to each other later on as needed.

Pulling out XRMToolbox, DataImport++ doesn't seem to want to allow me to map anything to my custom "WebAppCustomerID" field - so I'm thinking that route just may not support custom fields?

Going the PowerAutomate route, all the mapping looks great, but it doesn't seem to be built for moving any more than like 20-50 records at a time. Big dumps of 4k records seem to give me "Gateway Busy" errors.

Going the ADF route -- I think I just don't know ADF well enough, but it seems as though I can push data into DV and the mapping kinda works, but I have no idea how to get the GUID's "Back" into the SQLDB.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can define your WebAppCustomerID as [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/define-alternate-keys-reference-records) and easily use data importer.

[Upsert message with Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/use-upsert-insert-update-record?tabs=webapi)